# Equivalence of Lyapunov equation for continuous and discrete case

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, bilinear-form, lyapunov-functions

I am currently studying the original discrete/continous equivalence proof of the Lyapunov equation by [Rice 1967](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4207126).

1. Continuous case: $A^\star L + L A = -C$ for  $C \succcurlyeq 0$
2. Discrete case: $A^\star L A - L = -C $  for $C \succcurlyeq 0$

The paper claims that the discrete case can be derived from the continuous case by plugging in the bilinear transformation $ A = (B + I) (B - I)^{-1}$ into $A^\star L + L A = -C$ so that we eventually get $B^\star L B - L = -\frac{1}{2} Y$ for $Y = (B^\star - I) C( B - I)$ after some elementary transformations.

I have tried to reach the same results:

$$
A^\star L + L A = -C \\
[(B + I) (B - I)^{-1}]^\star L + L (B + I) (B - I)^{-1} = -C \\
$$
Multiplying from the left by $(B^\star - I)$ and from the right by $(B-I)$ yields:
$$
(B^\star - I)[(B + I) (B - I)^{-1}]^\star L (B-I) + (B^\star - I) L (B + I) (B - I)^{-1} (B-I) = -(B^\star - I) C (B-I) \\
\iff (B^\star - I) \left((B-I)^{-1} \right)^\star (B+I)^\star L (B-I) +  (B^\star - I) L (B + I) (B - I)^{-1} (B-I) = -(B^\star - I) C (B-I) \\
\iff (B^\star - I) \left((B-I)^\star \right)^{-1} (B+I)^\star L (B-I) +  (B^\star - I) L (B + I) (B - I)^{-1} (B-I) = -(B^\star - I) C (B-I) \\
\iff \underbrace{(B^\star - I) \left(B^\star-I \right)^{-1}}_{=I} (B+I)^\star L (B-I) +  (B^\star - I) L (B + I) \underbrace{(B - I)^{-1} (B-I)}_{=I} = -(B^\star - I) C (B-I) \\
$$
Which could be put as:
$$
(B+I)^\star L (B - I) + (B^\star - I) L (B +I) = -Y
$$
Which steps am I missing to complete the proof?

**P.S.**: The paper mentions the following identities of which I can't verify the last step either:
$$
 A = (B + I) (B - I)^{-1} \\
   = (B - I)^{-1} (B + I) \\
   = I + 2 (B - I)^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
(B+I)^\star L (B - I) =
B^\star LB-B^\star L+LB-B
$$
and
$$
((B^\star - I) L (B +I) =
B^\star LB+B^\star L-LB-B,
$$
which gives
$$
(B+I)^\star L (B - I) + (B^\star - I) L (B +I) =
2B^\star LB-2B=-Y.
$$

For the last identity, note that
$$
(B - I)^{-1} (B + I)= (B - I)^{-1} (B-I + 2I)  = I + 2 (B - I)^{-1}.
$$